# Oracle. Разность между последующим и текущим значением в столбце типа date

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Прошу руку помощи. Хотя бы в каком направлении думать, что читать.
Суть проблемы:
Есть таблица test_table

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо добавить расчетный столбец, где будет рассчитана длительность исполнения каждого шага, в секундах. Т.е. из времени следующего шага вычесть время текущего шага, перевести в секунды и положить в отдельный столбец. Соответственно расчет происходит для всех шагов, кроме крайнего.

[image: Результат]

Никак не могу понять, как к данной проблеме подступиться.
Любому совету буду благодарен.

Comment: Oracle db имеет функции `LEAD()/LAG()` для таких задач.

Comment: Yitzhak Khabinsky, спасибо большое, удалось решить данную задачу!)

Comment: Рад слышать, что вы решили проблему.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL**

```
select SESSION_ID
      ,PROCEDURE_NAME
      ,START_TIME
      ,DESCRIPTION
      ,((CAST(LEAD(START_TIME,1) OVER (PARTITION BY SESSION_ID,PROCEDURE_NAME ORDER BY START_TIME) as date) 
      - CAST(START_TIME as date))* 24 * 60 * 60) t
from test_table
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]